# a mathematical problem on inequalities

Tags: inequality

If $a,b,c,d$ are positive real numbers such that $a+b+c+d=1$,show that

$$  \frac{a^3}{b + c} + \frac{b^3}{c + d} + \frac{c^3}{d + a} + \frac{d^3}{a + b} > \frac 1 8$$

Comment: Can you share your thoughts on the problem, and explain what you've tried?

Comment: You may want to combine your terms into one and see what you get.

Comment: In case $a=b=c=d=\frac{1}{4}$, the equality holds, so you should insert equality sign there.

Comment: I forgot to insert equality sign. I got the equlity when a=b=c=d=1 but unable to prove the inquality

Comment: @lokesh Can you make the edit to the question then? Note that you stated the equatliy case wrongly, since $a+b+c+d=1$.

Answer (score 4):

By Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, we have$$\left(\sum_{cyc} \frac{a^3}{b + c} \right)\cdot \sum_{cyc}(b+c) \ge (a^{3/2}+b^{3/2}+c^{3/2}+d^{3/2})^2$$

So it is sufficient to show that $a^{3/2}+b^{3/2}+c^{3/2}+d^{3/2} \ge \frac12$.

But we have from Power Means inequality, 
$$\left(\frac{a^{3/2}+b^{3/2}+c^{3/2}+d^{3/2}}{4}\right)^{2/3}\ge \frac{a+b+c+d}{4}=\frac14 \implies a^{3/2}+b^{3/2}+c^{3/2}+d^{3/2} \ge \frac12$$

Equality is attained when $a=b=c=d=\frac14$.